# how to call the partial view from script function?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I am developing MVC application.

I want to call the partial view (which don't have any method in controller) from the function which is script of a view.

but its not working...

```
$('#PurchaseOrderId').blur(function (){
           @Html.Partial("ReturnsOfSinglePO")
});
```

Comment: You are mixing up server-side razor commands and client-side javascript. You can inject the page URL into the Javascript (if it is in a razor page), but you need to load it via an `$.ajax` call or similar (or set window.location for a simple redirect)

Comment: thnaks, do you have any sample...

Comment: Have done what I can below, but your question is very vague regarding the partial view *and what you want to do with it* :) If you provide a clear example of your page and partial view it may make more sense and will allow a specific answer that matches your code.

Comment: Make you a deal. If you can provide the details asked, I will add a new answer with just the parts you need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up server-side razor commands and client-side JavaScript.

### Ignore this bit for Partial view loads

You can inject the page URL into the JavaScript (if it is in a razor page), but you need to load it via an $.ajax call or similar (or set window.location for a simple redirect)

### e.g.

This will inject the URL into a JavaScript constant and assign it to window.location on blur:

```
$('#PurchaseOrderId').blur(function (){

           window.location = '@Url.Action("ReturnsOfSinglePO")';
});
```

But the javascript must be in the view for Razor injection to work.

If the Javascript is not on the same razor page, you can inject the page location into a property on the page (e.g. a DIV container) as a `data-` attribute and pick that up in the client-side code.

```
$('#PurchaseOrderId').blur(function (){
           window.location = $('.someClassYouAdded').data('url');
});
```

This assumes you you have injected the page URL into your view something like this:

```
   <div class="someClassYouAdded" data-ulr="@Url.Action("ReturnsOfSinglePO")"/>
```

### "Partial view changes things a bit"

Your use of the term partial view implies you want to load it into the current page. Use one of the ajax methods (like `$.get()`, `.load()` or `$.ajax()` etc). You will have to provide more detail of how you want the page updated to give a good example of this.

You will need a controller method "somewhere" to return a partial view. Controllers exist simply to map methods to URLs. Without a controller method you cannot return a random partial view.

For this example, add the following to the same controller that renders the current page in question:

```
public ActionResult ReturnsOfSinglePO()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

This assumes your partial view is in `Views/currentcontrollername/ReturnsOfSinglePO.cshtml` or in `/Views/Shared/ReturnsOfSinglePO.cshtml`

This will take an incoming URL request like `/currentcontrollername/ReturnsOfSinglePO` and return your partial view.

of course if you do this you can hard-wire the URL in your Jquery:

```
$('#PurchaseOrderId').blur(function (){

           $('.someClassYouAdded').load('/currentcontrollername/ReturnsOfSinglePO');
});
```

Where `someClassYouAdded` is a class added to the element you want to fill with the partial view.
*I am sure there are other ways to do this, but you must clearly separate your server-side HTML generation from client-side code (at least in your head) :)*

Comment: I dont have method in controller for this partial view... it returns the error...

Comment: Something server-side needs to return the Partial View (maps the URL to the server code). You have to have a controller method somewhere for a partial view to work.

Comment: I dont think its req. ... what if I have simple one line text in partial view ? should I write separate method in controller for it ?

Comment: Yes. Call it `ReturnsOfSinglePO` to match the view name and it only needs to do `return PartialView();`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts ...but U r confusing me... What exactly should I do ?

Comment: That's because there are possibly several options based on your requirements (which are not clear). I have updated the answer. If you want to load the partial view into an element on your page do the last parts under `Partial view changes things a bit`.